# Update Apache POI alone in WSO API Manager 2.6.0

Tags: java, wso2, apache-poi, wso2-api-manager

Need to Update Apache POI alone in WSO API-Manager 2.6.0 without disturbing core WSO API-M due to below mentioned vulnerability in APACHE POI.

[image: NESSUS SCAN REPORT For Apache POI <3.17]

Tried searching their document but couldn't get hold of though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just need http://poi.apache.org/download.html ?

Comment: I couldn’t find how to update it in ! Path inside wso apim